# Text to Speech call onPause After onCreate

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm using the Text to Speech engine in Android. I'm having problems with the way it calls onPause straight after onCreate. So first of all is there a way to stop this?

I have a game which has a MENU activity and a GAME activity; when the user hits the back button to go to the MENU activity from the GAME activity onPause is called, I'm using onPause here for some useful stuff like stopping a countdown and stopping the TTS engine.

My problem arises when onPause is called after onCreate and it tries to stop a counter that isn't counting and a TTS engine which isn't initialised. I've managed to sort the countdown by starting a spurious countdown on onCreate for the onPause to stop and I can probably do the same thing for the TTS engine but it's obviously not a great thing to be doing.

Can anyone think of another, cleaner way around this?

Thanks

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    timerCount.cancel();
    mTts.stop();
    mTts.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using onStop instead of onPause?

Comment: Hi Pedro - onStop isn't being called when I go back to the menu activity. To be honest I'm not 100% on Android lifecycle management, is there a way to force onStop to be called when I want it to?

Comment: What do you do (code) to get from the game activity to the menu activity? Do you finish the Game activity? Because if onStop is nto beeing called then your activity is not finished

Comment: I've not actually written any code for the switching back from the Game activity to the Menu activity, I've just relied on what android does automatically. Is there a way to control what happens when the back button is pressed?

Comment: I'm just reading about onBackPressed.

Comment: And onBackPressed do you call finish()? Also if onPaused is getting called onCreate (don't know how why) create a flag that controls that. Set it false on onCreate then on onPause if the variable is false set it to true and return. That way it will get called on the second call of the onPause

Comment: Thanks Perdo - I think both using onBackPressed and creating the flag would work for my original question; but I've just realised that if the user decides to go back to the menu without starting the game neither the countdown or the TTS engine will have started so I get the same problem. I solved it quite easily, I should have seen it before; all I needed to do was check to see if there have a countdown or a TTS before stopping them. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Is it just the first time onPause is called that you want to ignore?

Comment: @brandell it is and I think Perdo's work around would work but I've relised I need to do it in another way as I would get a problem if the user backed out without starting the game. It's all solved now though thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem in the future, the way to get around TTS calling onPause after onCreate and the problems that causes is to either use the onBackPressed command or (as Pedro mentioned) setting a flag which is false on onCreate and setting onPause to set it true.